# Async code in spark map function

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, apache-spark, mapreduce

I want to use spark for MapReduce task. Within my map function I use third party library for computations. The problem is that this library works asyncronously, something like this:

```
long id = lib.doJob(inputData); // start async job
```

I can then attach a listener to the library to get result, that's how it works:

```
lib.setListener(new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onDone(long id) {
        Result result = lib.getResult(id); // I can only get result this way
    }
    // ... other progress callbacks
});
```

So my question is - how can I use that library within my map function with spark? I want something like:

```
JavaRDD<Result> results = rdd.map(new MapFuntion<Source, Result> {
    public Result call(Source src) {
        long id = lib.doJob(src);
        // ... ?? wait while lib's job is done and get the result
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Personally I would feed this to the streaming job running a whole batch inside `mapPartitions` would be the next reasonable approach.